# USB ports in computer displays

Tags: usb, display, power-management

Many computer displays are have one USB in port and two USB out ports, maybe even more. Is that generally effectively a USB hub that does not get power from the rest of display hardware? Can I assume the ports' state is not altered just because the display is switched off or when the display enters some power management state?

Comment: I think if you use a powered USB Hub, what you want should work. I have done this, but my monitor only goes to standby (not off).

Comment: It depends on the monitor.  I have had monitors that cut the power when switched off and ones that continue to power the ports.  I have even had a monitor that made the ports unpowered but left the line open so lower power devices continued to function.

Comment: I'm not sure you can generalise. If I physically switch off my monitor, it stops providing power to my USB light & unmounts any connected drives - aggressively, ie they give the 'drive ejected improperly' warning. If I sleep it, the power stays on, the drives stay connected.

Comment: @Tetsujin What if you connect a keyboard in the USB port, switch the display off by physical button, and try to type something. Does the keyboard work then?  If you put your system to sleep state (S3), can you wake it up by keyboard (like you could when the keyboard is connected directly to computer)?

Comment: My system never sleeps [& isn't a PC so doesn't have an 'S3' state; it's a Mac] I can, therefore only test the difference between sleeping the screen itself, not the computer, & switching it off. I have always also followed the advice that 'important' devices should connect directly to the computer's own USB ports, not through any hub.